# Order purchase date filter range not showing expected results

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, order-grid

#### Preconditions

1. Magento 2.2.2, Nginx, Redis.
2. Magento local timezone AEDT,
3. server time AEDT
4. mysql SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(); returns AEDT time
5. SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; returns SYSTEM.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to Sales order grid
2. Apply purchase date range it should be a week or more in my case it's from 5-12-2018 to 12-12-2018 (7 days).

#### Expected result

1. It should display all orders in this range in my case it should show 42 orders.

#### Actual result

1. Not displaying all order in from 5-12-2018 to 12-12-2018 (7 days), its showing 39 Order and the last order is 000153. See below screenshot for reference.

[image: selection_123]

2. When I increase my date range in my case 4-12-2018 to 12-12-2018 (8 days) it's showing 3 more orders from 5-12-2018. See below screenshot for reference.

[image: selection_124]

Comment: I was faced same issue and debug to find cause of the Mirasvit_Report module conflict with the order date filter. I didn't need that module, then disabled to fixed date filter issue.

Comment: You can check same third party or your custom added module disabled once and check.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/Package/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Date">
        <plugin name="plugin_datatype_date" type="Vendor\Package\Plugin\Date"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Package/Plugin/Date.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Package\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Date as DateDataType;

/**
 * Class Date
 */
class Date
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $localeDate;

    /**
     * Date constructor.
     * @param TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     */
    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
    }

    /**
     * Convert given date to default (UTC) timezone
     *
     * @param DateDataType $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param $date
     * @param int $hour
     * @param int $minute
     * @param int $second
     * @param bool $setUtcTimeZone
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function aroundConvertDate(DateDataType $subject, callable $proceed, $date, $hour = 0, $minute = 0,
        $second = 0, $setUtcTimeZone = true)
    {
        try {
            $dateObj = $this->localeDate->date($date, $subject->getLocale(), true);

            $dateObj->setTime($hour, $minute, $second);
            //convert store date to default date in UTC timezone without DST
            if ($setUtcTimeZone) {
                $dateObj->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
            }
            return $dateObj;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```